# Why was this question closed? / Do we have a common "How to run .exe" question?

Tags: discussion

I find it surprising that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259649/ubuntu-wont-run-exe-files) was closed as off-topic.

I understand that the body of this question implies that the OP is neither seriously interested in this problem, nor that it is clear what kind of answer would be most appropriate, but I expected it to be closed as being a duplicate of "How do I run an .exe file in Ubuntu".

I believe this question is on-topic, it applies to a scenario I expect to be very common among users who come from Windows (*"So I installed Ubuntu, but I cannot run this .exe app I used on Windows..."*).

Please either:

- Point me to a general "How to run a .exe file on Ubuntu" question (*which I fail to find myself :-(* ), which would make the aforementioned question an exact duplicate (it would be worth to point to the common question from the closed duplicate), or
- Explain me the reasoning behind categorizing it as off-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We don't, we should make that one because googling for "How to run an .exe in Ubuntu" returns answers from Yahoo! Answers, and we can't have that!

I've retitled it and voted to reopen it so we can salvage, people were too quick to close it without thinking because it was about an old version without answering the actual question!

Comment: Great, thanks! Time to prepare an outstanding answer.

Comment: And I will prepare a fat bounty!